# Getting wrong results after simple multiplication - C++

Tags: c++

So, what needs to be done is: enter a real number and print the sum of its first 4 digits after the decimal point. E.g.: I enter 5.1010. I get to the point where I need to multiply 0.1010 by 10000 so it can become an integer, but the result I'm getting is 1009 instead of 1010 and everything falls apart after that.
I'd be forever thankful if someone can explain to me why does that happen.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double n;
  cout<<"Enter a positive real number: ";
  do
  {
    cin>>n;
    if(n<=0) cout<<"The number must be positive, enter again: ";
  }while(n<=0);

    //storing the fractional part in a var
  int y=n;
  double fr=n-y;
  //turning the fractional part into an integer
  int fr_int=fr*10000;
  cout<<fr_int<<endl;

  //storing each of the digits in a var
  int a=fr_int/1000;
  int b=fr_int/100%10;
  int c=fr_int/10%10;
  int d=fr_int%10;

  cout<<"The sum of the first 4 digits is: " << a+b+c+d;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change the code as follows, then it should be working.

```
  n *= 10000;
  int Integer = n;

  int i = 4;
  int sum = 0;
  while(i--)
  {
    sum += (Integer%10);
    Integer /= 10;
  }
  std::cout << "The sum of the first 4 digits is: " << sum;
```

Here is the output: https://www.ideone.com/PevZgn

**Update**:A generalized soln would be using `std::string`. However, would be great if the code is capable of handling exceptions in the case of non-numeric has been submitted by the user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string Number;
  double tempNum = 0.0;

  std::cout << "Enter a positive real number: ";
  do
  {
    std::cin >> Number;
    tempNum = std::stof(Number);

    if(tempNum <= 0)
      std::cout << "The number must be positive, enter again: ";
  }while(tempNum <= 0);

  bool Okay = false;
  int sum = 0;
  int i = 4;

  for(const auto& it: Number)
  {
    if(Okay && i > 0)
    {
      sum += static_cast<int>(it - '0');
      --i;
    }
    if(it == '.') Okay = true;
  }
  std::cout << "The sum of the first 4 digits is: " << sum;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add 0.5 before casting because the compile will always truncate the number.

In C++11 you can use std::round.

Comment: I did but my reputation is lower than 15 so it's not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Floating points and doubles in C++ aren't able to represent all decimal numbers accurately. In particular, 0.1, it cannot represent faithfully.

If you must be guaranteed that you get accurate results, you should either use fixed point math or a bignumber library.